# How can I implement life in Unity Engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm implementing life in Untiy Engine.

The life logic I implemented is trying to make a meteor lose 1 life when it hits the ground, and lose all lives when it collides with a player.

But I encounter the problem about this issue.

The first time the meteor hits the ground, it loses life, but it doesn't lose life after that.

I'm attaching it because I think that the problem is happening in the GM script and the meteor script, where life is diminishing.

GM Script

```
public int PlayerLife = 3;
[SerializeField] List<Image> List_Heart;

public void ShowHeart()
{
    if(PlayerLife == 2)
    {
        List_Heart[2].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    if(PlayerLife == 1)
    {
        List_Heart[2].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        List_Heart[1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    if(PlayerLife == 0)
    {
        List_Heart[2].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        List_Heart[1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        List_Heart[0].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Meteor Script

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GameManager.instance.PlayerLife = 0;
        GameManager.instance.ShowHeart();
    } 

    if (collision.CompareTag("Floor"))
    {
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GameManager.instance.PlayerLife--;
        GameManager.instance.ShowHeart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you notice that the ground disappears when the meteor hits the ground?

Comment: Well in the second case you probably do not want to do `collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);` ...

Comment: thks for answer.. I made a very stupid mistake.